# Given N and M find all stepping numbers in range N to M

Tags: c#, interview-questions

> The stepping number:
>
> A number is called as a stepping number if the adjacent digits have a
>   difference of 1. e.g 123 is stepping number, but 358 is not a stepping
>   number.
>
> Example:
>
> N = 10, M = 20
>
> All stepping numbers are 10, 12
>
> Return the numbers in sorted order.

---

The code I wrote does accomplish what is asked, but the complexity is \$O(n^2)\$ I think, and I'm sure there is a better way of doing this.

```
class Solution {
public List<int> stepnum(int A, int B) {
    List<int> result = new List<int>();
    for (int i=A;i<=B;i++)
    {
        string num = i.ToString();
        int amount = num.Count();
        int less = 0;
        bool step=true, ascending=true;

        if(amount>=2)  //0 - 1
        {
            for(int j=0;j<amount;j++)
            {
                ascending=true;
                if(j<amount-1)
                {
                    if((int)Char.GetNumericValue(num[j])>(int)Char.GetNumericValue(num[j+1]))
                    {
                        ascending=false;
                    }
                    if(ascending)
                        less=(int)Char.GetNumericValue(num[j+1])-(int)Char.GetNumericValue(num[j]);
                    else
                        less=(int)Char.GetNumericValue(num[j])-(int)Char.GetNumericValue(num[j+1]);
                    if(less!=1)
                    {
                        step=false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(step)
            {
                result.Add(Convert.ToInt32(num));
            }
        }
        else
            result.Add(Convert.ToInt32(num));
    }
    return result;
}
}
```

Comment: [Related question in Java](/q/74441/9357)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Code review

- Avoid unnecessary indentation whenever possible. An early exit block should always be on top. What I mean by that is this:

  ```
  for(...)
  {
      // this saves your 1-level of indentation
      if (amount < 2)
      {
          // update result
          continue;
      }

      // rest of code here
  }
  ```
- Use intermediary variables if the code gets too long and loses its meaning

  ```
  int current = (int)Char.GetNumericValue(num[j]), next = (int)Char.GetNumericValue(num[j+1]);
  if(current > next)
  {
      ascending=false;
  }
  if(ascending)
      less = next - current;
  else
      less = current - next;
  ```

  BTW, this can be simplfied to remove `ascending` variable:

  ```
  if(current > next)
  {
      less = current - next;
  }
  else
  {
      less = next - current;
  }
  ```

  Or, even better: `Math.Abs(current - next)`
- Put spaces around operators and control structures like `for`, `if`, `while`.
- You can also compare the [`char`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9h8tsay.aspx) directly, as "the value of a `char` object is a 16-bit numeric (ordinal) value": `'2' - '1' == 1`
- Don't work on numbers as a string and convert it back. It is highly inefficient.
- Divide your code. The block inside the first for-loop can be extracted into a `bool IsStepNumber(int)`.

---

## The Task

> The stepping number:
>
> A number is called as a stepping number if the adjacent digits have a difference of 1. e.g 123 is stepping number, but 358 is not a stepping number.

Basically, we need to (1)extract the digits, and (2)check if the adjacent digits have a difference of 1.

1. If you understand the [positional notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positional_notation), the extraction is pretty straightforward :

   ```
   public static IEnumerable<int> GetDigitsReverse(int value)
   {
       while(value > 0)
       {
           yield return value % 10;
           value /= 10;
       }
   }
   ```

   Due to the nature of this algorithm, the digits are in reserve order (right to left). Although it is really simple to re-reverse it (by chaining `.Reverse()`), it doesn't matter in which direction we are check the adjacent digits.
2. To compare adjacent items in a sequence, we can pair up a sequence with itself offset-ed by 1:

   ```
   public static bool IsSteppingNumber(int value)
   {
       var digits = GetDigitsReverse(value).ToList();
       return digits
           .Zip(digits.Skip(1), Tuple.Create)
           .All(x => Math.Abs(x.Item1 - x.Item2) == 1);
   }
   ```

To enumerate all step numbers in a defined range, we can use the following method:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> ListSteppingNumbersBetween(int a, int b)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(a, b - a + 1)
        .Where(IsSteppingNumber);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Background

I will first change some notation since I do not like that \$M \geq N\$.  Let \$A\$ be the minimum number in the range to check and let \$B\$ be the maximum number in the range to check.  The task is to return all Stepping Numbers inclusively between \$A\$ and \$B\$.

Be careful when trying to find Big O of your algorithm.  You assumed your algorithm was \$\mathcal{O}(n^2)\$ but you never defined what \$n\$ represents.  If you let \$n= B - A + 1\$ and \$d = log_{10}\,B\$ then your algorithm is \$\mathcal{O}(nd)\$ since you must iterate through \$n\$ numbers and perform an operation on each of the \$d\$ digits (on average) of each number.

## General Advice

This section is a mixture of coding style tips and finger-pointing at some sub-optimal code.  Most of this advice will not end up in updated code section, but I think it will be useful to you.

- Simplify the following loop

  ```
  for(int j=0;j<amount;j++)
  {
      ascending=true;
      if(j<amount-1)
      {
          ...
      }
  }
  ```

  Always prefer to handle an undesired condition immediately instead of adding a nested level to the rest of the code

  ```
  for(int j = 0; j < amount; j++)
  {
      ascending = true;
      if(j >= amount-1)
      {
          continue;
      }

      // Now we are assured j < amount-1
      ...
  }
  ```

  However, the real change to make here in this instance is to change the bounds on the loop

  ```
  for(int j = 0; j < amount-1; j++)
  {
      ascending = true;
      ...
  }
  ```
- Add more variables

  You refer to `Char.GetNumericValue(num[j])` 3 times in your code (although it is only evaluated potentially twice since 2 instances are in separate branches of an `if` statement).  Instead you should store the value as `currentDigit`.  Similarly, you should store `Char.GetNumericValue(num[j+1])` as `nextDigit`.  With these changes you can get rid of `ascending`.  The goal of this change is to make the code more readable.

  ```
  for(int j = 0;j < amount - 1; j++)
  {
      int currentDigit = Char.GetNumericValue(num[j]);
      int nextDigit = Char.GetNumericValue(num[j+1]);

      if(nextDigit > currentDigit)
      {
          less = nextDigit - currentDigit;
      }
      else
      {
          less = currentDigit - nextDigit;
      }

      if(less != 1)
      {
          step = false;
          break;
      }
  }
  ```
- Use absolute value to perform unordered differences.  At the end of the day you do not care if `Char.GetNumericValue(num[j])` is greater than `Char.GetNumericValue(num[j+1])` or not.  With this change you can get rid of `less`.

  ```
  for(int j = 0;j < amount - 1; j++)
  {
      int currentDigit = Char.GetNumericValue(num[j]);
      int nextDigit = Char.GetNumericValue(num[j+1]);

      if(Math.Abs(nextDigit - currentDigit) != 1)
      {
          step = false;
          break;
      }
  }
  ```
- Edge Cases

  Every single-digit number is a Stepping Number.  You handle this case separately in your code using the following `if` statement: `if(amount>=2) { ... } else { ... }`.  However, this `if` statement is not necessary.  The single-digit number case is handled just fine by the multi-digit number case.  In my opinion handling edge cases separately when they do not need to be only serves to make the code more unreadable.

  Always program the general case before edge cases.  After you have an implementation of the general case see if it handles the edge case or if not, what minimally invasive changes you can make to the general case to handle edge cases.  As a last resort, handle the edge case separately.
- Unnecessary operation

  You convert `i` to string `num` and then if `num` passes the Stepping Number test you convert `num` back to an integer and add it to the list with `result.Add(Convert.ToInt32(num))`.  Instead you could just use `i`: `result.Add(i)`.
- Use more descriptive names

  I know variable naming can be difficult, especially if you rarely use the terminology that best describes a variable, function, etc.  Here are some of the naming changes I would recommend.  Keep in mind I am not a C# programmer, but from a couple online searches I have commonly seen people use [PascalCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PascalCase) for functions in C# and [camelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) for variables in C# so this is the paradigm I will follow.

  `stepnum` should be `SteppingNumbers`, `amount` should be `numDigits`, `less` should be `difference`, `step` should be `isSteppingNumber`
- Create functions to perform tasks

  Separating the iteration from `a` to `b` from the logic to check Stepping Numbers makes the code more maintainable.

  ```
  public bool IsSteppingNumber(int number)
  {
      // Put the logic to check if number is a Stepping Number here
  }

  public List<int> stepnum(int a, int b)
  {
      List<int> steppingNumbers = new List<int>();

      for (int i = a; i <= b; i++)
      {
          if(IsSteppingNumber(i))
          {
              steppingNumbers.Add(i);
          }
      }
      return steppingNumbers;
  }
  ```
- Prefer to use the number directly rather than converting the number to a string.

  The internal workings of the function that converts a number to a string does all the work you would need to do behind the scenes.  Note that it does not matter what end of the number you start at when checking if a number is a Stepping Number or not.  Here is the general method to iterate through digits of a number:

  ```
  // Just assume number is 'positive for simplicity
  void SomeFunctionForPositiveIntegers(int number)
  {
      while(number != 0)
      {
          int digit = number % 10;
          number /= 10;

          DoSomethingWithDigit(digit);
      }
  }

  // Or if you need to handle 0 too
  void SomeFunctionForNonNegativeIntegers(int number)
  {
      do
      {
          int digit = number % 10;
          number /= 10;

          DoSomethingWithDigit(digit);
      } while (number != 0);
  }
  ```

## Updated Code

This is much simpler code that uses some of the advice I gave above.  In `IsSteppingNumber` we are iterating from right-most digits to left-most digits because it is simpler and because it does not matter what end we start on when checking for Stepping Numbers.

```
public bool IsSteppingNumber(int number)
{
    var prevDigit = number % 10;
    number /= 10;

    while(number != 0)
    {
        var currentDigit = number % 10;
        number /= 10;

        if(Math.Abs(currentDigit - prevDigit) != 1)
        {
            return false;
        }

        prevDigit = currentDigit;
    }

    return true;
}

public List<int> SteppingNumbersInclusivelyBetween(int a, int b)
{
    List<int> steppingNumbers = new List<int>();

    if (a < 0 || b < 0)
    {
        return steppingNumbers;
    }

    for (int i = a; i <= b; i++)
    {
        if(IsSteppingNumber(i))
        {
            steppingNumbers.Add(i);
        }
    }
    return steppingNumbers;
}
```

## Advanced

Assuming the range of numbers to check is large, there is a better way to solve this problem than the brute-force approach.  We can use the concept of induction and recursion to solve this problem in \$\mathcal{O}(2^d)\$.  For simplicity, the following approach does not handle the fact that zero is a Stepping Number.

Rather than checking all numbers between \$A\$ and \$B\$ to determine whether they are Stepping Numbers, we will instead generate a superset of Stepping Numbers in this range.  Let \$d_A\$ be the number of digits in \$A\$ and \$d_B\$ be the number of digits in \$B\$.  This approach generates all possible Stepping Numbers on \$[d_A,d_B]\$ digits.  We then filter this initial output to produce all Stepping Numbers between \$A\$ and \$B\$.

While you could generate the Stepping Numbers strictly between \$A\$ and \$B\$ without filtering at the end, doing so would either require you to either maintain two separate lists or generate unsorted output and then sort it later.

Generating the extra Stepping Numbers outside \$[A, B]\$ is not a big deal since there are not many Stepping Numbers in general.  For example, there are only \$3627\$ stepping numbers in \$[1, 2^{31} - 1]\$ which is the positive range of a 32-bit integer.

Assume you already have a Stepping Number \$S\$ of length \$l\$ and you want to append a digit to \$S\$ to create a Stepping Number of length \$l+1\$.  There are at most \$2\$ ways to do this depending on what the least significant digit (LSD) of \$S\$ is.

For instance, assume \$S = 43432\$.  The LSD of \$S\$ is \$2\$.  In order to append a digit and have the resulting number remain a Stepping Number, the appended digit must be \$1\$ or \$3\$ resulting in either \$S_1 = 434321\$ or \$S_3 = 434323\$ respectively.

It is important to realize that if you have all sorted \$n\$-digit Stepping Numbers then you can easily produce all sorted \$(n+1)\$-digit Stepping Numbers by iterating through each \$n\$-digit Stepping Number in order and, for each Stepping Number, appending digit \$\mathrm{LSD}-1\$ before \$\mathrm{LSD}+1\$.

```
public static int CountDigits(int number)
{
    // Does not handle number <= 0
    return (int)Math.Floor(Math.Log10(number)) + 1;
}

public static void ConstructSteppingNumbers(ref List<int> steppingNumbers, int number, int digit, int digitPosition, int numDigits)
{
    // Not a valid digit
    if(digit < 0 || digit > 9)
    {
        return;
    }

    // Construct the next Stepping Number
    number = 10 * number + digit;

    // Stopping Condition
    if(digitPosition == numDigits - 1)
    {
        steppingNumbers.Add(number);
        return;
    }

    // Create a (digitIndex+1)-digit Stepping Number from a digitIndex-digit Stepping Number
    // Test appending digit-1 before digit+1 to keep the output sorted
    ConstructSteppingNumbers(ref steppingNumbers, number, digit-1, digitPosition+1, numDigits);
    ConstructSteppingNumbers(ref steppingNumbers, number, digit+1, digitPosition+1, numDigits);
}

// Let number be a Stepping Number and let n be the number of digits in number
// This function adds any valid (n+1)-digit Stepping Numbers with prefix 'number' to the list
public static void ConstructNextDigitSteppingNumbers(ref List<int> steppingNumbers, int number)
{
    var LeastSignificantDigit = number % 10;

    // Check digit-1 before digit+1 to keep the output sorted
    if(LeastSignificantDigit - 1 >= 0)
    {
        steppingNumbers.Add(10*number + LeastSignificantDigit - 1);
    }

    if(LeastSignificantDigit + 1 <= 9)
    {
        steppingNumbers.Add(10*number + LeastSignificantDigit + 1);
    }
}

public static List<int> SteppingNumbersInclusivelyBetween(int start, int stop)
{
    var steppingNumbers = new List<int>();

    if(start <= 0 || stop <= 0)
    {
        return steppingNumbers;
    }

    var minNumDigits = CountDigits(start);
    var maxNumDigits = CountDigits(stop);

    // Construct all possible Stepping Numbers on minNumDigits digits
    ConstructSteppingNumbers(ref steppingNumbers, 0, 1, 0, minNumDigits);
    ConstructSteppingNumbers(ref steppingNumbers, 0, 2, 0, minNumDigits);
    ConstructSteppingNumbers(ref steppingNumbers, 0, 3, 0, minNumDigits);
    ConstructSteppingNumbers(ref steppingNumbers, 0, 4, 0, minNumDigits);
    ConstructSteppingNumbers(ref steppingNumbers, 0, 5, 0, minNumDigits);
    ConstructSteppingNumbers(ref steppingNumbers, 0, 6, 0, minNumDigits);
    ConstructSteppingNumbers(ref steppingNumbers, 0, 7, 0, minNumDigits);
    ConstructSteppingNumbers(ref steppingNumbers, 0, 8, 0, minNumDigits);
    ConstructSteppingNumbers(ref steppingNumbers, 0, 9, 0, minNumDigits);

    // The start of (numDigit-1)-digit Stepping Numbers
    var a = 0;

    // Reuse our work from earlier to generate Stepping Numbers on a higher
    // number of digits if necessary.  While we could have generated these
    // Stepping Numbers earlier, the output would not be sorted if we had.
    for(var numDigits = minNumDigits+1; numDigits <= maxNumDigits; numDigits++)
    {
        // The end of (numDigit-1)-digit Stepping Numbers
        var b = steppingNumbers.Count();

        // Construct numDigit-digit Stepping Numbers from (numDigit-1)-digit Stepping Numbers
        for(var i = a; i < b; i++)
        {
            ConstructNextDigitSteppingNumbers(ref steppingNumbers, steppingNumbers[i]);
        }

        a = b;
    }

    // Filter the Stepping Numbers to be within the range
    steppingNumbers.RemoveAll(number => (number < start || number > stop));

    return steppingNumbers;
}
```

The reason that we do not handle zero being a Stepping Number is that appending a digit to zero does not result in a new unique number compared to what we already had.  There are a few different relatively simple ways to include zero in the output if necessary.

Note that I used more comments in this code than I normally would in an attempt to be make this post more instructional.  I do not want you to be under the impression that you need to comment 50% of the code.  I generally only comment lines that are not *self-evident*.  Whatever that means depends on the context.

As a final note, if you do not like recursion then you can generate all \$1\$-digit to \$d_B\$-digit Stepping Numbers instead.  You would initialize `steppingNumbers` with all 1-digit Stepping Numbers (except 0) and use `ConstructNextDigitSteppingNumbers` to create higher-digit Stepping Numbers.  The advantage is the code would be simpler (you could remove `ConstructSteppingNumbers`) and a potential disadvantage is creating and filtering a larger list which could be slower.

Comment: Side note: If you needed to simply count the number of Stepping Numbers in \$[A, B]\$ this could be done using \$\mathcal{O}(1)\$ memory and \$\mathcal{O}(d)\$ time.

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry for this but your solution seems so convoluted that i am going to completely disregard it.

A valid approach for this algorithm would be as follows:

- Let `currentNumber` = `N`
- Get all digits of `currentNumber`
- Check that Math.Abs(d<sub>(i)</sub> - d<sub>(i+1)</sub>) == 1, where d<sub>(i)</sub> is the current digit
- Increment `currentNumber`, Repeat until `currentNumber` = M

An implementation on `C#` would result in something like this:

```
public bool IsStepNumber(int number){
    var digits = number.ToString()
        .Select(d => d - '0')
        .ToArray();

    for(int i = 1; i < digits.Length; ++i){
        var previous = digits[i-1];
        if(Math.Abs(previous - digits[i]) != 1){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public IEnumerable<int> SteppingNumbers(int min, int max){
    for(var i = min; i <= max; ++i){
        if(IsStepNumber(i)){
            yield return i;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: alternately `return Enumerable.Range(min, max-min).Where(IsStepNumber)`

Comment: @Caleth There are \$b-a+1\$ numbers in \$[a, b]\$ so it would be `return Enumerable.Range(min, max-min+1).Where(IsStepNumber)`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps more efficiently you could parse each number as an integer instead of casting to a string:

```
public static bool IsStepNumber2(int num)
{
    int current = 0;
    int prev = -1;
    while (num > 0)
    {
        current = num % 10;
        if (prev != -1)
        {
            if (Math.Abs(prev - current) != 1)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        prev = current;
        number = num / 10;
    }
    return true;
}

public static IEnumerable<int> SteppingNumbers(int start, int end)
{
      yield return Enumerable.Range(start, end-start).Where(x => IsStepNumber2(x))
}
```

Comment: Don't need to use good

Comment: yep, changed my mind part way through and forgot to remove it.  thanks.